# Unable to Gain input when loop terminates

Tags: c++, c, c++11

Hi All ham trying to count the number of words and characters etc.. for a project, however, in the line where I input ^D to terminate input, that line is not counted in the words characters etc..

Any line where the input terminates it does not count. Furthermore, for some reason it does not print the statements at the bottom when I run the program, but it does when I debug it.

Would appreciate your help on the same.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int input;
    int words =0;
    int charecters =0;
    int spaces =0;
    int newline =0;
    int tab= 0;
    int total =0;
    int dummy;
    int lastChar;
    printf("Please start your input and press ^D to terminate:\n");
    while ((input=getchar())!= EOF)
    {
        if(input == ' ')
        {
            ++spaces;
        }
        else if(input =='\n')
        {
            ++newline;
            fflush(stdin);
        }
        else if(input == '\t' )
        {
            ++tab;
        }
        else
        {
            charecters++;
            dummy = input;
        }


        lastChar = input;
        if(dummy != lastChar)
        {
            words++;
        }

        total++;
    }
    printf("The total number of keyboard strokes was %d.\n", total);
    printf("The total number of charecters is %d\n", charecters);
    printf("The number of new lines is: %d\n", newline);
    printf("The number of  space is: %d\n", spaces);
    printf("The number of  tabs is: %d\n", tab);
    printf("The number of new words is: %d\n", words);

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Hi! And welcome to StackOverflow! Are you adamant on using your own function or would you be willing to use some c++ functions that make the problem easier to solve? Also, I do not see any `str` variable in your code

Comment: Ctrl-D isn't really EOF.  It's a character sequence that your terminal interprets as end-of-input, and EOF is a condition on a file handle indicating that there's no more bytes to be read.  In LInux shells, Ctrl-D must be entered on a new line to have the desired effect, I think.

Comment: To make it short: This code can´t produce this error. Please adjust the illustrated code.

Comment: @RobertSsupportsMonicaCellio I have adjusted this code. Apologise for the previous mistake.

Comment: @DanielFarrell I am using macOS Catalina on CLion IDE. Whenever I hit enter and press ctrl D there is no problem.

Comment: `"word word word WORD(EOF)"` when your program reads `(EOF)`, it quits the while loop, hence the `"WORD"` did not get counted

Comment: regarding: `if(dummy != lastChar)`   There are several execution paths where the variable `dummy` is not initialized.

Comment: regarding: `fflush(stdin);`  The C standard specifically states that this is undefined behavior (although Visual Studio has an implementation)  Usage of this statement makes the code non portable.  Suggest: `int ch;  while( (ch = getchar()) != EOF && ch != '\n' );`

Comment: the languages `C` and `C++` are different languages.  The posted code is written in `C`.  Please remove the `tags` for other languages

Comment: regarding the logic of the posted code.  Strongly suggest implementing a `2-state machine` where the two states are `in_word` and `not_in_word`.  Then word counting is only performed in the transition between `not_in_word` to `in_word`

Comment: regarding: `fflush(stdin);`  Why throw away ALL following input when you reach the end of a sentence?   What if the input was from a file?  With the current code, only the first sentence would be processed and all following sentences would be discarded

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the following proposed code:

1. performs the desired functionality
2. cleanly compiles
3. implements a state machine with 2 states
4. on LINUX, recognizes `<ctrl-d>` as end of input, which must be the first character on a new line
5. incorporates a `switch` statement to keep each 'activity' clearly recognizable
6. uses appropriate horizontal and vertical spacing for ease of readability and understanding
7. does not correct the spelling of `characters`

and now, the proposed code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( void )
{
    int input;
    int words      = 0;
    int charecters = 0;
    int spaces     = 0;
    int newline    = 0;
    int tab        = 0;
    int total      = 0;

    printf( "Please start your input and press ^D to terminate:\n" );

    enum { inWord, notInWord } state = notInWord;
    while ( (input=getchar())!= EOF )
    {
        ++total;

        if( input == ' ' || input == '\n' || input == '\t' )
        {
            state = notInWord;
        }

        switch( input )
        {
            case ' ':
                ++spaces;
                break;

            case '\n':
                ++newline;
                break;

            case '\t':
                ++tab;
                break;

            default:
                charecters++;
                if  (state == notInWord )
                {
                    state = inWord;
                    ++words;
                }
        }
    }

    printf( "The total number of keyboard strokes was %d.\n", total );
    printf( "The total number of charecters is %d\n", charecters );
    printf( "The number of new lines is: %d\n", newline );
    printf( "The number of  space is: %d\n", spaces );
    printf( "The number of  tabs is: %d\n", tab );
    printf( "The number of new words is: %d\n", words );

    return 0;
}
```

a typical run of the program:

```
Please start your input and press ^D to terminate:
lkfjaiennf;aliea vliesge lsker'
flkaiwore
The total number of keyboard strokes was 42.
The total number of charecters is 38
The number of new lines is: 2
The number of  space is: 2
The number of  tabs is: 0
The number of new words is: 4
```

Notice that the program does not recognize punctuation as a word separator.  Suggest including the header file: `ctype.h` to make the code more robust by using the functionality of:

```
ispunc()
isdigit()
isspace()
```